# Finding places within a particular distance of a point using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, gis, distance

I'm working on a task as part of a project which finds the places within a certain distance of a particular (lat, long) point. I know the way to get the result for a single row in my table which has the (Latitude, Longitude) point and the corresponding distance (given by Coverage_Norm_10km, in my case).

My database table (Sorted_Range_Cap_Data) is of the following form:

---

Place , Population, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Bandwidth_Required, Coverage_Range, Throughput_Range, Coverage_Norm_10km, Throughput_10km

```
SELECT
  Place, (
   6371 * acos (
    cos ( radians(17.741150) )
    * cos( radians(Latitude) )
    * cos( radians(Longitude) - radians(73.149712) )
    + sin ( radians(17.741150) )
    * sin( radians(Latitude) )
   )
 ) AS Coverage_Norm_10km
 FROM Sorted_Range_Cap_Data
 HAVING Coverage_Norm_10km < (The current row's "Coverage_Norm_10km" value)
 ORDER BY Coverage_Norm_10km
 LIMIT 0, 20;
```

(Source : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-points-within-a-distance-using-mysql)

Here, (17.741150, 73.149712) is a (lat, long) point in the first row of my database table. I want to find the set of all places which are within "Coverage_Norm_10km" distance from the (lat, long) point.

I need to repeat this for each row in the table.

Finally, I want to end up with the list of places for each (lat, long) point (every row) in my table.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html)?

Comment: I did, but I would prefer some simpler way using an SQL query. Kindly let me know, if you have a way through the use of queries.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Could you provide a query which solves my problem. I am stuck on this since long and would request some help. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to compare every location in the table with every other location in the same table? I think you'll need to provide some sample data and a desired result, perhaps as an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: Yup exactly. That's what I want. I'll provide it right away.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4TogYI7E9KXOHpUcnNsZ2hGbWM/view?usp=sharing

Here's the file containing sample data. As for the output, I just need Place, Coverage_Norm_10km for each row in the table.

Sorry, I don't know how to use sqlfiddle so I used google docs.

Waiting for your kind reply at the earliest.

Comment: A little clarification on my comment above, I need list of "Place"s and their corresponding "Coverage_Norm_10km" that are within "Coverage_Norm_10km" distance for every row (lat, long) of the table. Hope it's very clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar using the Haversine formula in nodejs, here's my raw query:

```
var query = "SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" + req.query.latitude + ") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) " +
        " * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(" + req.query.longitude + ") ) + sin( radians(" + req.query.latitude + ") ) * sin(radians(latitude)) ) ) AS distance " +
        " FROM account " +
        " HAVING distance < 10 " +
        " ORDER BY distance " +
        " LIMIT 0 , 20;";
```

My accounts table stores each record's latitude/longitude. This would return all accounts within 10 miles of my requested lat/lng.

Comment: I got your point. But if you read my question carefully, I want a suitable query which returns the list of places for each row of the table. How shall I modify my sql query to achieve the desired outcome ? I am stuck on this.

Comment: Then you could simply loop over your rows and supply the lat/lng from the row to the query above, that would give you a list of places for each row. You may be able to achieve this with a nested select but i'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: That I know. But I don't know how ! Will wait for other replies as well.